# ERROR: Spider error processing <GET - .parse callback not defined

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm extremely new to python and scrapy. I've tried running existing code and I'm getting these errors thrown. I'm running the latest version of scrapy on windows 10 and using Visual Code Studio to run my tests in, etc.

**Terminal Debug**

```
2020-12-07 20:52:52 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.newegg.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2020-12-07 20:52:52 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.newegg.com/asus-radeon-rx-6800-rx6800-16g/p/N82E16814126473> (referer: None)
2020-12-07 20:52:52 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://www.newegg.com/white-bluedio-ht-wireless/p/0TH-0357-00002?Item=9SIACD56WH3830> (referer: None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 654, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spiders\__init__.py", line 90, in _parse
    return self.parse(response, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\scrapy\spiders\__init__.py", line 93, in parse
    raise NotImplementedError(f'{self.__class__.__name__}.parse callback is not defined')
NotImplementedError: NeweggSpider.parse callback is not defined
```

**egg_spider.py**

```
class NeweggSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "newegg"
    USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) " \
                 "Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36 "
    allowed_domains = ['newegg.com']
    start_urls = [
        "https://www.newegg.com/white-bluedio-ht-wireless/p/0TH-0357-00002?Item=9SIACD56WH3830", ]

def parse(self, response):
   # Finding Product Status.
    my_list = []
    try:
       product = response.xpath("//*[@class='btn btn-primary btn-wide']//text()").get().strip()
       my_list = [product]
       print(f"Product is Currently: {my_list}")
    except AttributeError:
       pass
```

Any help in the most layman's terms possible. Thanks!

Comment: You need to move your `def parse()`  inside your `class`

Comment: Perfect! That's exactly what I needed. Runs perfectly now. Thanks again! @gangabass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to indent your code as per  gangabass comment.

```
import scrapy

class NeweggSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "newegg"
    USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) " \
                 "Chrome/43.0.2357.130 Safari/537.36 "
    allowed_domains = ['newegg.com']
    start_urls = [
        "https://www.newegg.com/white-bluedio-ht-wireless/p/0TH-0357-00002?Item=9SIACD56WH3830", ]

    def parse(self, response):
       # Finding Product Status.
        my_list = []
        try:
           product = response.xpath("//*[@class='btn btn-primary btn-wide']//text()").get().strip()
           my_list = [product]
           print(f"Product is Currently: {my_list}")
        except AttributeError:
           pass
```